# datatables.yajrabox laravel 5.4 error

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, yajra-datatable

using laravel 5.4 I get an error when I try to run the index view.
Checking in firebug, I get this:

ErrorException in Datatables.php line 57:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

My routes:

```
Route::get('promotions.data', 'PromotionController@getPromotions')->name('promotions.data');
Route::resource('promotions', 'PromotionController');
```

My ajax call:

```
$('#promotionsTbl').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{!! url('promotions.data') !!}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                    { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
                    { data: 'from_date', name: 'from_date' },
                    { data: 'to_date', name: 'to_date' }
                ]
            });
```

My Controller:

```
public function getPromotions()
   {
       return Datatables::of(Promotion::query())->make(true);
   }
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try without renaming or use `name: promotions.id`

Comment: You may be have this [issue](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/issues/1505). Try `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: God bless you both. I think what helpes was the cache:clear

Answer (score 1):

just clear config cache of laravel.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

delete datatables.php file and run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=datatables
```

or

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=datatables --force
```

it's work for me